# jQuery - Show hidden div and check cookie

Tags: jquery

I've made this small campaign popup box, but I need the class .popupbox to be display:none, or else it will blink/show up on site refresh or change. But how could I change my jQuery script to show the hidden div? and check the cookie before showing the div?

```
<div class="popupbox" id="popupboxToggleDiv">
  <a href="#" id="campaign_Toggle">
    <div class="close_button"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="campaign_text">Free shipping</div>
</div>

<script>
  if (jQuery.cookie("toggle") == "toggled")
    jQuery("#popupboxToggleDiv").hide("fast");

  jQuery('#campaign_Toggle').click(function () {
    jQuery('#popupboxToggleDiv').fadeOut('slow');
    jQuery.cookie("toggle", "toggled");
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set show in **else** condition like:

```
<script>
    if (jQuery.cookie("toggle") == "toggled")
        jQuery("#popupboxToggleDiv").hide("fast");
    else
        jQuery("#popupboxToggleDiv").show("fast");

jQuery('#campaign_Toggle').click(function () {
    jQuery('#popupboxToggleDiv').fadeOut('slow');
    jQuery.cookie("toggle", "toggled");
    return false;
});
</script>
```